# how to construct a better Ratings Table in mySQL? is it appropriate like this?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new to mySQL, and I need help on constructing a table. Here are the conditions:

1. Each user is allowed to rate only once at per restaurant (second rating onward will be update of the previous record).
2. Average = (AverageQuality + AverageService + AverageClealiness)/ NumofRates
3. AverageQuality = all user's (userRateQuality) / number of users rate..
4. AverageService = all user's (userRateService) / number of users rate..

The following is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratings` (
    `Average` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `AverageQuality` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `AverageClealiness` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `AverageService` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `NumofTotalRates` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `userID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `restaurantID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `userRateQuality` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `userRateService` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `userRateClealiness` int(5) NOT NULL
)
```

I know it is weird but I have been bothered by this question for a few days, and I do not know how to fix this schema or construct a better one. I need some suggestions/guidance. Please reply or ask any question as it might helps to improve my table. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table structure doesn't really make sense.  You should store each user's rating for quality, cleanliness and service. So you could do something like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ratings (
   userID varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
   restaurantID int(11) NOT NULL, 
   userRateQuality int(5) NOT NULL, 
   userRateService int(5) NOT NULL, 
   userRateClealiness int(5) NOT NULL )
)
```

Once you have this data, you can run queries to get the average ratings.  You wouldn't want to store average ratings within the same table that stores a user's ratings because the average changes each time someone adds a new rating.  To get the average, you can use the MySQL AVG function.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert! it make sense to me.. Average changes all the time.. thanks for your guidance!